# Oracle 12c cloning resulting in internal error code

Tags: oracle, clone, pdb, cdb

I'm trying to clone an Oracle 12c pluggable database from a remote host, but I'm receiving an internal error code with very little to debug with:

```
SQL> CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE CLONED_PDB FROM SRC_PDB@RCDB;
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE CLONED_PDB FROM SRC_PDB@RCDB
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[], [], []
```

Both machines have Oracle 12c installed, and I have admin access on both. I'm also able to clone locally on the remote host, which makes me think it's a file permission issue, but I don't know what I'd need to `chmod`. The redacted script, run from localhost as sysdba in SQL*Plus:

```
---------- REMOTE HOST ----------

-- Connect to remote host
CONN sys/password@//remotehost:1521/cdb0 AS SYSDBA

-- Drop existing user
DROP USER C##NEW_RCU;

-- Create user in remote PDB
CREATE USER C##NEW_RCU IDENTIFIED BY new_rcu;

-- Grant privileges to remote user
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA, CREATE SESSION, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO C##NEW_RCU;

-- Connect to source PDB
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE SRC_PDB CLOSE IMMEDIATE;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE SRC_PDB OPEN READ WRITE;
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=SRC_PDB;

-- Grant create privileges to remote user
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA, CREATE SESSION, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO C##NEW_RCU;

-- Connect to CDB
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=CDB$ROOT;

-- Open source PDB in read-only mode
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE SRC_PDB CLOSE IMMEDIATE;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE SRC_PDB OPEN READ ONLY;



---------- DESTINATION HOST ----------

-- Connect to destination host
CONN sys/password@//localhost:1521/cdb0 AS SYSDBA

-- Drop existing DB link
DROP DATABASE LINK RCDB;

-- Drop database if it exists
DROP PLUGGABLE DATABASE CLONED_PDB;

-- Create database link in root container
CREATE DATABASE LINK RCDB CONNECT TO C##NEW_RCU IDENTIFIED BY new_rcu USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=remotehost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SRC_PDB)))';

-- DEBUGGING ONLY
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL@RCDB;

-- Clone remote PDB
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE CLONED_PDB FROM SRC_PDB@RCDB;

-- Open new PDB in read/write mode
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE CLONED_PDB OPEN;
```

Everything - including the `select sysdate from dual@rcdb` - works as expected except for the last 2 commands.

Any idea how to debug this, or any steps I can try to get this clone to work?

Comment: You should look on My Oracle Support, and raise a service request if you can't find this issue already reported.It looks similar to Doc ID 2072550.1, but that's with Active Data Guard, not just read-only.  Is there anything more specific in the alert log or any trace files it may have created?

Comment: No, unfortunately there was nothing was logged to the trace log. Thanks for the tip, I haven't found anything yet on Oracle Support but I'll post back here if I find an answer or workaround.